# Applying The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Tags: calculus

What is the maximum value $\int_0^1f(x)x^{2009}dx$ can be over all functions $f(x)$ that are integrable with $\int_0^1f^2(x)dx=1$?

How does the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality apply here?

Comment: Perhaps you should instead ask: when does the CS *equality* apply here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\large\left(\int_0^1f^2(x){\rm d}x\right)\left(\int_0^1x^{4018}{\rm d}x\right)\ge\left(\int_0^1f(x)x^{2009}{\rm d}x\right)^2$$
and equality is achieved iff $f(x)=\lambda\cdot x^{2009}$ (almost everywhere) for some $\lambda$.

Comment: You might want to double check this

Comment: @SimonS does it seem correct now the 2019?

Comment: Also, $\left(\int fg\right)^\color{red}{2} \leq \int f^2 \int g^2$

Comment: Following this hint I got the following:
$[\int_0^1 f(x)x^{2009}dx]^2 \leq (\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx)(\int_0^1 x^{4018}dx)$
$[\int_0^1 f(x)x^{2009}dx]^2 \leq \frac{1}{4019} \rightarrow$
$\int_0^1 f(x)x^{2009}dx \leq \frac{\sqrt{4019}}{4019}$

Comment: @Michelle yes it seems correct